# Creating a Key Table and Domain Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

All,

I need to add a domain class for a new key table that relates a table of club members ([dbo].NewClubProspect) to emails ([dbo].NewClubEmail) sent to them.

I am not sure how to set this up in the domain classes.

**Question**
Need to annotate the key table (NewClubProspectNewClubEmail) Since both properties are foreign keys, not sure if I need an actual primary key, too? How do I annotate this?

Here is a diagram of how the tables relate. The table on the bottom of the diagram (NewClubProspectNewClubEmail) is the new table that I need to create in the database and in code, in a domain class.

[image]

Here are my domain classes (chopped down for brevity)

```
      public  class NewClub
      {


            public NewClub()
            {
                NewClubProspects = new List<NewClubProspect>();
                NewClubEmails = new List<NewClubEmail>();
            }


            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string NewClubName { get; set; }
            public string NewClubLocation { get; set; }
            public string NewClubType { get; set; }
            public string NewClubCity { get; set; }
            public string NewClubState { get; set; }
            public string NewClubCountry { get; set; }



            public virtual List<NewClubProspect> NewClubProspects { get; set; }
            public virtual List<NewClubEmail> NewClubEmails { get; set; } 

        }



   public class NewClubProspect
   {

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Foreign Key
    public int NewClubId { get; set; }

    public bool IsConverted { get; set; }
    public string ProspectFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ProspectLastName { get; set; }
    public string ProspectEmail { get; set; }


    public virtual NewClub NewClub { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewClubEmail> NewClubEmails { get; set; } 
}


 public class NewClubEmail
 {
        //Primary key
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Foreign Key
        public int NewClubId { get; set; }


        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual List<NewClubProspect> Recipients { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }

        public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }

        public NewClubEmail()
        {
            Recipients = new Collection<NewClubProspect>();
        }


     }

 //---------------------------------------------------------
// Not sure what to do here. They are both foreign keys
//---------------------------------------------------------
public class NewClubProspectNewClubEmail
{
   public int NewClubEmail_Id    {get; set;}
   public int NewClubProspect_Id {get; set;
}
```

Comment: Your approach looks good to me. However, those are not PK (as shown in your diagram) but FKs.

Comment: No, you don't need a PK for this table as this is only a helper-table.

Comment: @Dunken Wondering why I am getting EF errors saying I need to define a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark both as Key:

```
[Key]
public int NewClubEmail_Id    {get; set;}

[Key]
public int NewClubProspect_Id {get; set;}
```